# Proving $J_n(x)N_{n+1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x)N_n(x)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi x}$: Part $1$ of $3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

This is the first part of a proof that $J_n(x)N_{n+1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x)N_n(x)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi x}$:

> Write Bessel's equation $$x^2y^{\prime\prime}+xy^{\prime} + (x^2 - p^2)y=0\tag{1}$$ with $y=J_p$ and again with $y=J_{-p}$; multiply
>   the $J_p$ equation by $J_{−p}$ and the $J_{−p}$ equation by $J_p$ and subtract to get $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x\left(J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}\right)\right]=0\tag{2}$$

So I wrote $(1)$ with $y=J_p$:
$$x^2J_p^{\prime\prime}+xJ_p^{\prime} + (x^2 - p^2)J_p=0\tag{3}$$
and again with $y=J_{-p}$:
$$x^2J_{-p}^{\prime\prime}+xJ_{-p}^{\prime} + (x^2 - p^2)J_{-p}=0\tag{4}$$

Multiplying $(3)$ by $J_{-p}$:

$$x^2J_p^{\prime\prime}J_{-p}+xJ_p^{\prime}J_{-p} + (x^2 - p^2)J_pJ_{-p}=0\tag{5}$$

Multiplying $(4)$ by $J_{p}$:

$$x^2J_{-p}^{\prime\prime}J_{p}+xJ_{-p}^{\prime}J_{p} + (x^2 - p^2)J_{-p}J_{p}=0\tag{6}$$

Subtracting $(6)$ from $(5)$ gives:

$$x^2\left[J_p^{\prime\prime}J_{-p}-J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime\prime}\right]+x\left[J_p^{\prime}J_{-p}-J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}\right]=0\tag{7}$$ Rewriting the second term of $(7)$ and cancelling the $x$'s as $x\ne 0$ gives
$$x\left[J_p^{\prime\prime}J_{-p}-J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime\prime}\right]+\left[J_pJ_{-p}\right]^{\prime}=0\tag{8}$$ but I'm not sure if this is helping.

Could anyone please give me some hints or advice on how I can obtain equation $(2)$? $$\bbox[#AFA]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x\left(J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}\right)\right]=0}\tag{2}$$

Many thanks.

---

### EDIT:

In response to the answer given by @okrzysik

\begin{equation}
x[(J_{p}'' J_{-p} + J_{p}' J_{-p}') - (J_{p} J_{-p}'' + J_{p}' J_{-p}')] + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\implies x[(J_{p}'J_{-p})' - (J_{-p}'J_{p})'] + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0.
\end{equation}

I'm still unsure how to show that this is equal to $$\bbox[#AFF]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x\left(J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}\right)\right]=0}\tag{2}$$

Could anyone please assist me on these final steps?

Thanks again.

Comment: You already proved it... expression in your last step is equivalent to that of your question.

Comment: I mean, your $(7)$ is already the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the $[J_p J_{-p}]'$ term in your equation (8) is not correct, writing out equation (8) correctly gives

\begin{equation}
x[J_{p}'' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}''] + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0.
\end{equation}

Now consider adding and subtracting $x J_{p}' J_{-p}'$ on the LHS side of this equation:

\begin{equation}
x[(J_{p}'' J_{-p} + J_{p}' J_{-p}') - (J_{p} J_{-p}'' + J_{p}' J_{-p}')] + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0.
\end{equation}

Now we can recognise the grouped terms in the first bracket as derivatives. The equation can thus be written as

\begin{equation}
x[(J_{p}' J_{-p})' - (J_{p}J_{-p}')'] + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0,
\end{equation}

So we can also write

\begin{equation}
x[J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p}J_{-p}']' + [J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p} J_{-p}'] = 0.
\end{equation}

You should now notice that these two terms do indeed come from differentiating a single term with the product rule, namely $x[J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p}J_{-p}']$ and hence

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}[x(J_{p}' J_{-p} - J_{p}J_{-p}')] = 0
\end{equation}

as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when you say "adding and subtracting $x J_{p}' J_{-p}$" you only apply it to _one_ side of the equation right? Also, please see my edit, as I am unsure how to continue this calculation to reach the desired result. Could you please elaborate further? Thank you.

Comment: @BLAZE, yes it was redundant for me to say add and subtract it from both sides as the nett affect of doing so is adding zero anyway. I've updated my answer as per your edit; I hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks very much!

Comment: @BLAZE glad I could help. Also just another quick point, you shouldn't really "cancel the $x's$ as $x \neq 0$": $x$ is allowed to be zero, and indeed the Bessel functions are well defined at zero. Instead you should factor out an $x$ from your expression so that you have something like $x \times Y = 0$ then you can conclude that $Y = 0$ because $x \neq 0$ **in general**.

Comment: Okay, I'll bare that in mind; thanks for your time.