# Proving $J_n(x)N_{n+1}(x)-J_{n+1}(x)N_n(x)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi x}$: Part $2$ of $3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

The following question is the second part to this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829439/proving-j-nxn-n1x-j-n1xn-nx-dfrac2-pi-x-part-1-of-3):

> Prove that $$J_p(x)J_{-p}^{\prime}(x)-J_{-p}(x)J_{p}^{\prime}(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi x}\sin(p\pi)\tag{1}$$ from [$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[x\left(J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}\right)\right]=0\qquad\longleftarrow\text{(Proved in Part 1)}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829439/proving-j-nxn-n1x-j-n1xn-nx-dfrac2-pi-x-part-1-of-3) it follows that $$J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}=\frac{c}{x}\tag{2}$$ To find $c$ use $$\fbox{$J_p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1+p)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+p}$}\tag{3}$$ for each of the $4$ functions and pick out the $\dfrac{1}{x}$ terms in the products. Then use $$\fbox{$\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(p\pi)}$}\tag{4}$$

Writing out the $4$ functions:

$$J_p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1+p)\cdot 2^{2n+p}}\tag{a}$$

$$J_p^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n+p)\cdot x^{2n+p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1+p)\cdot 2^{2n+p}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\tag{b}$$

$$J_{-p}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n-p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-p)\cdot 2^{2n-p}}\tag{c}$$

$$J_{-p}^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-p)\cdot x^{2n-p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-p)\cdot 2^{2n-p}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\tag{d}$$

Insertion of $(\mathrm{a})$, $(\mathrm{b})$, $(\mathrm{c})$, $(\mathrm{d})$ into $(2)$ gives

$$\bbox[#AFF]{
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1+p)\cdot 2^{2n+p}}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-p)\cdot x^{2n-p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-p)\cdot 2^{2n-p}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}\quad-\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n-p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-p)\cdot 2^{2n-p}}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n+p)\cdot x^{2n+p}}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1+p)\cdot 2^{2n+p}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}=\frac{c}{x}
}$$

So unless I'm mistaken this means that the highlighted equation above requires that 
$$J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}=c\tag{5}$$

If this is the case then insertion of $(5)$ into $(2)$ implies that
$$J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}=\frac{J_pJ_{-p}^{\prime}-J_{-p}J_{p}^{\prime}}{x}\implies x=1$$

I'm not sure if what I have done so far is correct, also I have no idea how to make use of $$\fbox{$\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(p\pi)}$}$$

Could anyone please provide some feedback, hints or tips on how I can prove that 
$$\fbox{$\color{red}{J_p(x)J_{-p}^{\prime}(x)-J_{-p}(x)J_{p}^{\prime}(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi x}\sin(p\pi)}$}$$

Much appreciated.

Comment: You are mistaken: after you simplify $1 \over x$ the second an fourth highlighted summation are no more $J'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find $c$ such that $$x\left[J_{p}\left(x\right)J'_{-p}\left(x\right)-J'_{p}\left(x\right)J_{-p}\left(x\right)\right]=c.$$ We use $$J_{p}\left(x\right)=\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m}}{\Gamma\left(m+1\right)\Gamma\left(p+m+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+p}$$ $$
 J_{-p}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\Gamma\left(-p+k+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k-p}$$ $$
 J'_{p}\left(x\right)=\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{l}\left(2l+p\right)}{\Gamma\left(l+1\right)\Gamma\left(p+l+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2l+p-1}$$ $$
 J'_{-p}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(2n-p\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)\Gamma\left(-p+n+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n-p-1}$$ We observe that $$x\left[J_{p}\left(x\right)J'_{-p}\left(x\right)-J'_{p}\left(x\right)J_{-p}\left(x\right)\right]$$
 $$=\sum_{n\geq0}\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+m}\left(2n-p\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)\Gamma\left(m+1\right)\Gamma\left(-p+n+1\right)\Gamma\left(p+m+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+2m}
 $$ $$-\sum_{k\geq0}\sum_{l\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+l}\left(2l+p\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+1\right)\Gamma\left(l+1\right)\Gamma\left(-p+k+1\right)\Gamma\left(p+l+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2p+2l}
 $$ $$=-{\sum_{u\geq0}\sum_{v\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+v}{\left(2p-2u-2v\right)}}{\Gamma\left(u+1\right)\Gamma\left(v+1\right)\Gamma\left(p+u+1\right)\Gamma\left(-p+v+1\right)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2u+2v}}\tag{1}$$ where $(1)$ follows from the fact that the we have two double series with the same addends and opposing sign.
  So $$\begin{align}
{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x\left[J_{p}\left(x\right)J'_{-p}\left(x\right)-J'_{p}\left(x\right)J_{-p}\left(x\right)\right]}= & -\frac{2p}{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(1-p\right)} \\ = & -\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(p\right)\Gamma\left(1-p\right)} \\
 = & -\frac{2\sin\left(p\pi\right)}{\pi}.
\end{align}$$ Note that the calculation of the limit follows from the fact that if we take $x\rightarrow 0$ the only non vanish term is when $m=n=0$ since it doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: @BLAZE Sorry but it is not a typo. Maybe I should use different letters for each series. $2n$ comes from $J'_{p}$ and it is not equal to $2m$. When you have multiple series you have to use different letters to avoid ambiguity. I use only $m,n$ since I thought it was more simple to note that we combine together the series. If you want I add more details.

Comment: @Marco Yes please could you add more details. I thought it was an $m$ because the inner summation is being differentiated, right?

Comment: @Marco Thanks, in $(1)$ what happened to the $2l$?

Comment: @BLAZE You have two double series which converge absolutely so you can rearrange. Note that we have the same addends with opposite sign, so we can put together. In $(1)$ I used other letters so you can see it is another (equivalent) form of the difference of the two series. The letters are not important, the important is that the addends are the same so we can put in only one double sum.

Comment: @Marco Thanks, so $2n\,,2l\rightarrow 2u\,,2v$ in the final summation $(1)$?

Comment: @BLAZE Yes, I only change the letter.

Comment: @Marco All makes sense now thanks very much :-)